# "boost_interprocess" folder appearing in Mac Documents folder

Tags: boost-interprocess

I searched StackOverflow and found two threads referring to "boost interprocess" but both of them basically just address the Windows OS and also are not discussing the problem I'm having. The same search on Google is the same problem -- Windows OS and also most of the discussions are years old.

**My Problem:** On my iMac (Mojave OS) a folder has suddenly popped up in my Documents folder with the name "boost_interprocess". Inside the folder is a document with the name "pdfEngine-10.0.472-0a71a373-fe27-499f-be0c-2d67402dc128_shm". Everytime it has appeared I have deleted it and emptied the trash. It randomly appears the next day or a few days later. I've run Malwarebytes and it does not recognize it as a threat.

**My Question:** Does anyone know what this is and how to permanently delete it?

Answer (score 0):

The boost_interprocess folder is one of the methods for inter-process communication by means of shared memory, and you may see this folder on other OSs since it is a [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) mechanism.

The file(s) you see in the folder are named shared memory objects.

In your case, it looks like some PDF engine data is shared in such a way, and there's no cause for alarm.

Answer (score 0):

### Quark XPress created this folder on my Mac

It can be created for several process, but in my case it was QuarkXPress, as outlined in this [Ask Different post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/359934/169745) (the details in the QuarkXPress support post link have unfortunately expired).